# Как запретить приплюсовывание больше 0 mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Это рабочий пример выполнения запроса, при котором приплюсовывается в поле, но с условием что приплюсовка не бдует работать когда в поле стоит 0, все указано в коде.
Вопрос как сделать что бы не только при значении 0 не срабатывало приплюсовывание, а еще и все что выше ноля 0<+1.

```
  $this->db->query("
        update users
        set `noter_a` = `noter_a` + 1
        where 
          id = '".intval($get_o['user_id'])."' 
          AND `noter_a` != 0
    ");
```

Comment: заменить `!=` на `<=` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо)

Comment: Ну и не лишним будет заметить, что формировать таким образом запрос не правильно. Используйте `$this->db->bind_param`

Comment: @rjhdby спасибо за коменнтарий, можно по подробней,$this->db->bind_param